# Two electron state

Tags: quantum-mechanics

> If two electron are in the state $|s, m\rangle = |1, −1\rangle$. In a
> measure of $S_{1z}$, what are the possible value and probability
> obtained.

I am not sure if i understood the question, but, since the electron's spin is 1/2, in oder to have "m = -1", we need both spins down, so the possible value obtained is $(-\hbar/2)$ with prob = 1? I am not sure if this is right, honestly i am confused.

Comment: If you imagine looking at inner products of the form $\langle s,m| s_1,s_2; m_1, m_2\rangle = \langle 1,-1 | 1/2,  1/2; m_1, m_2 \rangle$, what values of $m_1$ and $m_2$ would you need to look at to answer this question? Do you know about [Clebsch-Gordan coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients)? You can read off the inner products you need from a [table of Clebsch-Gordan coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients#_j1_=_1/2,_j2_=_1/2).

Comment: I  agree with your reasoning.

Comment: @Andrew i know a little about it. But i am not sure if it is necessary here. Do you think my answer is right using only logical reasoning? i mean, without Clebsch Gordan

Comment: Yes, it looks fine.